# How to run VSCode Integrated Terminal in x86_64 on Apple M1 (arm64)?

Tags: terminal, apple-silicon, visual-studio-code, rosetta

VSCode now has an arm64 version, problem is there are still a lot of command-line developer tools that are using x86_64 architecture.

At the moment there doesn't appear to be a plugin or preferences to load the Integrated VSCode Terminal in a specific `arch`.

```
# load up the Integrated Terminal in VSCode
echo $TERM_PROGRAM # will say vscode

# check arch
arch # will say arm64 if you have Apple M1
```

Comment: Why not just run VSCode in Rosetta?

Comment: will try and add answer @MarcWilson

Comment: @MarcWilson tried it and the Rosetta option wasn't available for VSCode app

Comment: @sonjz You can try downloading the Intel-only VSCode here https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled with trying to add another shell, etc, but found the easiest thing was to update your shell config to look for `vscode`.  Once a `zsh` session loads and detects you are in the Integrated `vscode` Terminal, it will launch another shell within the arch

Add this to your `~/.zshrc` or whatever shell config you are using:

```
# simulates iTerm i386 within VSCode Integrated Terminal
if [[ $TERM_PROGRAM == "vscode" ]] && [[ $(arch) == "arm64" ]];
then
  exec arch -x86_64 $SHELL
fi

# you may notice if you exit the terminal an abrupt 127 error, but shouldn't be an issue.
```

Comment: Could you replace the running terminal with `exec` ?  Hm, would that work cross-architecture?

Comment: hmm just noticed, running in /bin/zsh loop when in integrated, i'll take a look

Comment: `exec` works great @MarcWilson!  also fixed looping bug